# What is the probability that at most 2 jobs will be completed within the constructed time period?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

A large construction firm estimates that 10% of the jobs that it manages are finished within the constructed time period. It looks at a random sample of 5 jobs that it has managed.
What is the probability that at most 2 jobs will be completed within the constructed time period?

Q. Im unsure of how to solve this. Would it be correct to use the exponential distribution function with lambda=1/(0.10(5)) and integrate it over [0,2]?

Comment: Well, if the number of jobs is large enough so that we can assume independence, I'd just use the binomial distribution.

Comment: Come to think of it, what I inquired does not even make sense does it since the possible values of the random variable X are discrete not continuous (where X=number of completed jobs in the time period). I suppose binomial distribution is ideal. Thanks

Comment: What value would I use for the probability p in the binomial distribution? would it be 0.1?

Comment: Yes.  Again, assuming the number of jobs is large. If there are exactly $10$ jobs the answer is very different.

Comment: Why is a large number of jobs required to assume independence? My understanding of independence in this context is: a job being finished does not affect another job being finished within the time period.

Comment: Look at my example with exactly $10$ jobs, exactly one of which gets finished on time.  In that case the answer to your question is obviously $1$.  That's because of independence.  With exactly one job finished on time, if the first one is finished on time then the second is not.  For a large number, you can safely ignore the changes in probability caused by each trial.